# Derive arbitrary steps between two expressions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

Can someone show me the syntax to find the algebraic transformations between:

$\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx$

and

$\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$

And more generally, how to get the algebraic derivation between two expressions?

Answer (score 1):

One way might be

```
 ClearAll[dy, dx]
 expr = Sqrt[1 + (dy/dx)^2] dx
```

[image]

```
  expr = expr /. dx*Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[dx^2*x] (*assumes dx>0*)
```

[image]

```
  expr /. Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[Expand[x]]
```

[image]

Or using `Simplify`

```
 expr = Sqrt[1 + (dy/dx)^2] dx;
 Assuming[dx > 0, Simplify[expr]]
```

[image]

Mathematica was not really designed to show the steps of transformation or solution. May be Wolfram Alpha might be better choice for these things. (it has a `Show Steps` options).

I also know your `dx` is meant to be differential and your `dy/dx` is meant to be derivative. But Mathematica does not work with differentials as separate variables.

And if you want to see how Mathematica converted it with Simplify, you can try to look at output of `Scan`

```
expr = Sqrt[1 + (dy/dx)^2] dx;
Trace[Assuming[dx < 0, Simplify[expr]], TraceInternal -> True]
```

but it is hard to follow the output from this command.

Comment: You mentioned WolframAlpha. Can you show the exact command in Wolframalpha that can show the steps? I don't know the syntax to generate the "Show Steps" between two different expressions.

Comment: @user3180 I do not use Wolfram alpha much. But if you go to the web site, and type command there, its A.I. engine will try to understand what you meant and solve it, then normally it will have an option at top right called "Show steps". If you click on it, it will show the steps it used. Not for all commands, but for number of them this option comes up automatically.

Comment: yes, it shows steps for single expression, but not for comparing two expressions.